# なぜ型が合うのかわからない

Tags: rust, bevy

下記 add_startup_system の呼び出しがあります。

https://github.com/frederickjjoubert/bevy-ball-game/blob/Episode-3/src/main.rs#L12

```
.add_startup_system(spawn_camera)
```

---

add_startup_system の定義は下記です。
https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/v0.10.0/crates/bevy_app/src/app.rs#L465

```
pub fn add_startup_system<M>(&mut self, system: impl IntoSystemConfig<M>) -> &mut Self {
```

引数に IntoSystemConfig を満たすものを要求していると思います。

---

実際にadd_startup_systemに与えているのは、下記関数ですので、下記関数がIntoSystemConfigを満たしているようには見えないのですが、どういう仕組みなのでしょうか？　またどのように読めば、満たしているとわかるのでしょうか？
https://github.com/frederickjjoubert/bevy-ball-game/blob/Episode-3/src/main.rs#L43-L50

```
pub fn spawn_camera(mut commands: Commands, window_query: Query<&Window, With<PrimaryWindow>>) {
    let window = window_query.get_single().unwrap();

    commands.spawn(Camera2dBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(window.width() / 2.0, window.height() / 2.0, 0.0),
        ..default()
    });
}
```

Comment: Rustのbevy::windowの仕様に関係しているのではないですか？

Answer (score 0):

`IntoSystemConfig`は、`IntoSystem<(), (), Marker>`を満足する全ての型に対して実装されると記載があります。
https://docs.rs/bevy_ecs/0.10.0/bevy_ecs/schedule/trait.IntoSystemConfig.html#impl-IntoSystemConfig%3CMarker,+SystemConfig%3E-for-F

`IntoSystem`のドキュメントを見ると、このtraitは`ExclusiveSystemParamFunction`または`SystemParamFunction`を満足する全ての型に実装されると書かれています。

次に`SystemParamFunction`のドキュメントを……という風に、順々に最後まで追いかけていくと、おそらくこの関数は結果的に`IntoSystemConfig`を満足するのではないかなと思います。
（`SystemParamFunction`以降はproc macroで自動生成される型なのでちゃんと追いかけてはいませんが……）